# Pages access to users depending on multiple modules status enabled or disabled

Tags: php, sql

I have a scenario, where I have a page table and that page is enabled or disabled based on multiple modules. One page can be dependent on multiple modules, and a module is dependent on another module. If any of the modules from them are disabled then the page will be disabled. Also if page itself is disabled, it will not bring a record. I have a status field in a module table and a page table both that show if it is enabled or not. For this I have created a middle table where I am storing dependencies. But I am not finding any way in sql how I can do it. See the sql tables below, if you can give me a better solution for it.

1)File Table

```
file_id|  file_name           |   file_title         |display_in  |dependent_on
    1  |user_configuration.php|  User Configuration  |3             | 4
```

2)File Dependencies(middle table)

```
id |  module_id | file_id
1  |  3         |   1
```

3)Modules Table

```
module_id | mudule_name           |   status
3         | Configuration module  |     1
4         | Customers module       |    0
```

Comment: attachment is not showing please show your sql tables and queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $qry =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files f 
    LEFT JOIN file_dependencies fd on fd.file_id = f.file_id
    LEFT JOIN modules m on m.module_id = fd.module_id where fd.module_id = '3'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    if($row['display_in'] && $row['dependent_on']){
      // write your own custom code
    }
  }
```

You need to use the joins in the table and check the dependencies and displays in the php code

Comment: i just changed some conditions in sql and it works, however thanks for the support